# Apache httpd rewrite rule to use LDAP user group

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, reverse-proxy, kibana

I am trying to add LDAP based authorisation to Kibana 3 without using Shield or other 3rd party tools.

Given the index name is `logstash-*`, my original thinking is to utilize rewriting rules in httpd, rewrite kibana request into `logstash-[ldap-usergroup]-*`, and prepare a set of index aliases in elasticsearch that with different filters, thus to achieve the authorisation at the LDAP user group level.

The problem I am facing currently, is how do I get the `usergroup` value after the authentication block and use it into the rewrites?

assume I have something like

```
<Location />
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=username, CN=Users, DC=domain, DC=com"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "Password for Kerberos auth user"
AuthLDAPURL "ldap(or ldaps)://fqdns or ip of ldap/adserver/CN=users,DC=domain,DC=com"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthName "some text for login prompt"
require valid-user
</Location>
RewriteCond   %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} !^$
RewriteRules  /es/(.*)logstash-([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)(.*) /es/$1%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}-$2$3 [N]
```

ie. how do I make sure rather than the username, I can have a usergroup name value available before doing the rewrite?

Borrowed some codes from here: thanks to them
https://gist.github.com/kakbit/6192679
http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/LDAP-authentication-in-Kibana-td4057946.html

Answer (score 0):

I think if your'e using `mod_authnz_ldap` you can use the directive - `"Require ldap-group"` and secure the particular *Kibana pertaining to a index*. 
[Here's the link for more details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#reqgroup) -
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but this isn't quite an answer to my question. I stated already that I am trying to use the `index alias` with filter to isolate ldap user to see different elasticsearch documents, depending on their group. 
`Require ldap-group` only authenticates user by group, but can't pass that `group name` as a variable to further help the url rewriting (where I was asking help for)

Answer (score 0):

I actually got this working as OP described, not perfect but worked. The trick is to use different subdomains in uri to explicitly separate users by their groups. ie. there are `/kibana/finance`, `/kibana/hr`, `/kibana/management` etc.. and these finance, hr, or management are mapped to particular LDAP groups, with which, in rewriting, I can use the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable to do the url rewriting.